# GPPShareBuilderImpl getURL Content deep-link ID is required with title and description

Tags: iphone, google-plus

I need to share photo on google plus:

Things I did are:

AppDelegate.m

```
static NSString * const kClientId = @"MyClient ID";
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientId;
```

on button click

```
- (IBAction)SharePressed:(id)sender {

id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

// This line will manually fill out the title, description, and thumbnail of the
// item you're sharing.
[shareBuilder setTitle:@"Try Sharing g+" description:@"demo" thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://UrlForShaingPhoto/asd/imagename.jpg"]];

[shareBuilder open];
```

But on Click it shows me

```
[lvl=3] -[GPPShareBuilderImpl getURL] Content deep-link ID is required with title and description.
```

and nothing happens.

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what it's saying - you need to supply a deep link ID if you're not supplying a URL. So, try adding:

```
[shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"my_id_here"]
```

In case you're wondering why you have to do this - it's so that the share can go somewhere. If we don't have a URL, the assumption is that we can go to a mobile app, so we need a deeplink ID. If your app is configured for deep linking then a user tapping that post on mobile will be take back to the app: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share#deep_linking

Answer (score 0):

Check This out dude

[ID is required with title and description](http://www.4byte.cn/question/580623/gppsharebuilderimpl-geturl-content-deep-link-id-is-required-with-title-and-description.html)

Or [Choosing a deep-link identifier](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/deep-link)

```
  [shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:kClientID];
  [shareBuilder setTitle:@"Check this out!"
                description:@"I jhave acheived it!"
                thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://52.74.199.191//resources/images/login-logo.png"]];
```

You can use only one way `[shareBuilder setURLToShare` or

```
[shareBuilder setTitle:title
                            description:description
                           thumbnailURL:imageUrl]
```

> **You can build content deep links in two ways:**
>
> 1. Passing a URL to setURLToShare: and passing a deep-link identifier to
>      setContentDeepLinkID:. Google retrieves the content at the URL and
>      extracts from it a title, description and thumbnail URL to populate
>      the share dialog.
> 2. Passing the title, description, and thumbnail URL to
>      setTitle:description:thumbnailURL: and passing a deep-link identifier
>      to setContentDeepLinkID:. Choose this approach when you do not have a
>      URL to retrieve the information to populate the share dialog.